# Python Image array modified between save/load

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I am modifying images using Image and Numpy in Python 2.7.
I am saving an image with a numpy Integer grayscale array using :

```
img = Image.fromarray(grayscale_arr, 'L')
img.save(output)
```

In an other function, i reopen the same image and get the grayscale array with :

```
img = Image.open(output)
grayscale_arr = np.array(img)
```

However the arrays do not match. The differences are not big but significant enough ...

My questions are : 
First why is that ? Is it an imprecision of some sort ? (just out of  curiosity)
And how can I fix this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe you are using a weird file format that does not fully support the precision or whatever else is the image. I know nothing about this so I can't help you more, but maybe this is the reason

Comment: What format are you saving the image as? Are you sure you've picked a lossless format?

Comment: I am a moron,  I used jpeg instead of PNG ! Thank you !